# AS2 -problems with loaded object

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, loader

I have a loder that loades swf that plays on enterFrame event .

I want the sound from the loaded swf will start on RollOver event , and not at the moment when the obhect is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply create an rollOver event, and move there your code that start sound? I would suggest also create some flag which you will set in loader, this way you will know if the sound is already available or not

```
some_object.onRollOver = function() {
  if(sound_available == true){
    //your play sound code here
  }
}
```

Comment: the sound isn't a single file it is coming with a flv that run on the swf, that louded. I simply wants that on rollOver the sound will play

Comment: so you use some component that play this flv video. This component should have some volume parameters. You should set volume to 0 on onLoad event, and later set it to the right value on onRollOver event.

Comment: it set to 0 , but how do i call to him from the loader ?

Comment: Is loaded swf made by you? do you have access to it's code? because to call it you should create connection to it (flash or JS), but anyway you need to have acceess to it. In the beginning i thought loader and this swf movie is a part of one big flash. But now i'm understanding that they are not.